# Save the State of changing colors

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a little Problem with my code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {



        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {



                $(this).each(function() {

               var classes = ['blue','red','green','none'];
               this.className = classes[($.inArray(this.className, classes)+1)%classes.length];


                            });

                    }
            })



    });



    </script>
```

```
     <div class="top">
          Arbeitsplaner <br>

     </div>

     <div id='calendar'></div>

    <div class='description'>

        rot = Ganztag <br>
        blau = Halbtag <br>
        grün = Frei

    </div>
```

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH6hR.png)

The changing of the colors work fine, but every time I switch to another month or reload the page the colors are gone...

How can i save the state of the colors?

I'm just a starter at JS right now, sorry if it is a easy question :)

Comment: Its time for cookies...

Comment: can you show me an example how to use cookies in my code? :)

Comment: https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anwendung_und_Praxis/cookies

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 `localStorage` for saving data.
ex:

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
localStorage.getItem("key");
```

In this case you can save state of your color. [check this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) link to know more.